# How to elegantly grab data with python?

Tags: python

I have data in text file and I need to store it in database and now I little bit confused how to do it easier.

Here is an example of my data:

```
a: text1
b: text2
c: text3
blah blah not necessary text
a: text4
b: text5
c: text6
etc
```

So can you help me to parse this data. 
I already done next code

```
import urllib2 as ur

def getPageData(url):
    return ur.urlopen(url).readlines()

checkList = ['a', 'b', 'c']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    textList = getPageData(url)
    res = []
    for i in textList:
        for y in checkList:
            if y in i:
                print i
```

I create a table in base something like

```
id | a varchar | b varchar | c varchar |
```

and I expect next result

```
id | a varchar | b varchar | c varchar |
1  | text1     | text2     | text3     |
2  | text4     | text5     | text6     |
n  | text      | text      | text      |
```

if read text file line by line how can I divide this text to logical blocks, for example I get a,b,c create dictionary with this data, and next when this block ends I append dictionary to list, and after that I have list of dict to store it to base. But I little bit confused how to create this list with this dictionary what I need to check and how to avoid unnecessary data in it? Is there more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Do you know the names of the identifiers (`a, b, c`) beforehand?

Comment: Yep i know it. They not changed but repeat through all text.

Comment: How will the row `id` value be determined, and how do you group the `a`, `b` and `c` values into a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd split on the `:` colon and test if the first part is in the set of allowed prefixes:

```
checkList = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])

for i in textList:
    check, rest = i.split(':', 1)
    if check.strip() not in checkList:
        continue
    data = rest.strip()
    # insert data into database; check is your column name.
```

Comment: Thnx, Martijn. I' try it now.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
text = """a: text1
b: text2
c: text3
blah blah not necessary text
a: text4
b: text5
c: text6
etc."""

import re
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for line in textList:
    m = re.match(r"([^:]+):\s*(.*)", line)
    if m:
        d[m.group(1)].append(m.group(2))
```

Then you get

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['text1', 'text4'], 'c': ['text3', 'text6'], 
'b': ['text2', 'text5']})
```

The regular expression identifies lines that contain at least one identifier (`a`, for example), then one colon, and it puts the identifier and the text following the colon (`.*`) into the match's groups. It then puts the results into a "default dictionary" that creates its contents as they are being introduced.

If you know the identifiers beforehand, you can use

```
m = re.match(r"(a|b|c|otherid|diff_id|etc)\s*:\s*(.*)", line)
```

instead.

Comment: Thnx Tim for this solution. I'll also try it now. Is a collections default module?

Comment: @IshikawaYoshi: Yes, it's in the standard library.